# How may I update an array that's in a MongoDB using Spring?

Tags: spring-data-mongodb

I'm trying to update database information from some information I get from a Thymeleaf powered page. Basically each page is constructed using a single document from MongoDB. Now I'd like to allow some users to change this page, since the actual page is not that complex, I was giving a shot to this JavaScript plugin that would create text area divs and send them to server via Ajax (http://www.dyve.net/jquery/?editable).

Since the document has only unique fields, I can set the field id in the html to the name of the mongodb field, like product-description. I can send the id through and the update is really simple:

```
public boolean updateValueWithKey(String id, String k, String v) {
    Criteria c = Criteria.where(id).is(id);
    Query q = new Query().addCriteria(c);
    Update u = u.set(k, v);
    WriteResult w = operations.updateFirst(q, u, clazz);
    return w.wasAcknowledged();
}
```

Where id is the document id code, k is the field name (key) and v the value.

But I realized that one particular part of the document has an array, but I don't understand how can I update a particular field of an array.

The Update class has a inner class called PushOperatorBuilder with a method called atPosition, which the docs mention that: "Forces values to be added at the given {@literal position}."

But I really don't understand how to use that, any attempt to reach that method from the instantiated Update object just gave me errors.

Help?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can try [postional operator](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/positional/#update-documents-in-an-array) to locate array field in a query followed by update at that position.

Something like

```
Criteria c = Criteria.where(id).is(id).and("array.key").is("oldvalue");
Query q = new Query().addCriteria(c);
Update u = new Update().set("array.$.key", "newvalue");
WriteResult w = mongoOperations.updateFirst(q, u, clazz);
```

Update at [specific position](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/position/)

```
Criteria c = Criteria.where(id).is(id);
Query q = new Query().addCriteria(c);
Update u = new Update().push("arrayname").atPosition(position).each(newvalue);
WriteResult w = mongoOperations.updateFirst(q, u, clazz);
```

Comment: I don't have the oldvalue, nor I want it. I have the literal position I want to update

Comment: Welp, that emptied my whole document xD 
Gonna take some time reading through the docs you posted and will be checking out. What's weird about your answer is that inside the array there are 3 fields, but the PushOperatorBuilder doesn't seem to have a key/value update option.

Comment: OH I GOT IT. Took me a while to realize but you should use dot notation to reach within the array, so array.$.key becomes array.0.key or array.1.key. Thanks Veeram!